# Connection to container of DataStax Distribution of Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax

I created Docker container of DataStax Distribution of Apache Cassandra (DDAC):

```
docker pull datastax/ddac
docker run -e DS_LICENSE=accept --name ddac -d datastax/ddac

docker ps
```

[image]

---

I got the error while connecting to the node via Datastax DevCenter:

[image]

The same error occurred during try connect via 7000 and 7199 ports.

---

**How to connect to DDAC node deployed in a docker container?**

---

### UPDATE

I disabled Windows Firewall just in case.
Use `docker run -e DS_LICENSE=accept --name ddac -p 9042:9042 -d datastax/ddac` and got same error:

> The specified host(s) could not be reached. All host(s) tried for
>   query failed (tried: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException:
>   [localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] Channel has been closed),
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException:
>   [localhost/127.0.0.1] Channel has been closed))
>   [localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] Channel has been closed
>   [localhost/127.0.0.1] Channel has been closed

[image]

Comment: that's another error - now DDAC is exposed correctly... I think that DevCenter isn't compatible with newer Cassandra versions  - it's not longer maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because container has it's own IP, and you need to either connect to it - you can get the IP of container with

```sh
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' ddac
```

or expose Cassandra ports on the host, so you can connect via localhost - this is done via `-p` flag of `docker run`:

```sh
docker run -e DS_LICENSE=accept --name ddac --rm -p 9042:9042 -d datastax/ddac
```